# Does there exist RestFixtureimplementation with JSON comparing or better helper functions for RestFixture FitNesse testing

Tags: json, fitnesse

I have a webservice that returns a JSON response like this:

```
{
"status": "OK",
"product": {
    "productId": "123456",
    "fields": [
            {
                "key": "season",
                "value": "summer"
            },
            {
                "key": "weigth",
                "value": "10kg"
            },
            {
                "key": "label",
                "value": "fun"
            },
            {
                "key": "target",
                "value": "indoor"
            }
        ]
}
}
```

The field order is random. I cannot expect field entry X to be the same on each request.

I am attempting to use RestFixture and have set up something like this - more or less:

```
|!-Table:smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture-! | http://localhost:8080/MyService/json|
|setHeader|!-Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8-!|
|POST|/getFoo|200|!-Server : Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type : application/json
Content-Length : 455-!|jsonbody.status=="OK"|
|let | noOfFields| js | response.jsonbody.product.fields.length| 4.0| 
|let | checkAllFieldKeys| js | !- response.jsonbody.product.fields[0].key=='target' 
                            or response.jsonbody.product.fields[1].key=='target' 
                            or response.jsonbody.product.fields[2].key=='target' 
                            or response.jsonbody.product.fields[3].key=='target' 
                           -! |true|
```

The test goes green but is very tideous to set up, i.e. have to use dot-notation into every branch.

Is there a RestFixture implementation that has succeeded in comparing JSON objects better?

Or, is there a better way to write this type of test perhaps with functions that assign to variables and/or a "contains" function?

```
| let | targetFieldExist| js |response.jsonbody.product.fields.contains('key'=='target') | true|
| let | targetField| js | response.jsonbody.product.fields.get('key'=='target') | |
| let | targetValueExists| js | $targetField.value == 'indoor' | true|
```

Answer (score 1):

as per RestFixture documentation, currently available [here](https://cloud.github.com/downloads/smartrics/RestFixture/RestFixture-3.0.pdf) (section LetTestsV2):

> If the context of the let row is js the expression is evaluated as
>   a javascript string. The value assigned to the let label is the result
>   of the evaluation of the content in the expression cell.

as such you can write any javascript there in.

```
|let | checkAllFieldKeys| js | !-
var res = false;
for(var i=0, len = response.jsonbody.product.fields.length; i < len; i++) { 
    if(response.jsonbody.product.fields[i].key == 'target') { 
        res = true; 
        break; 
    } 
};
res;
-! | |
```